# 1 to 1 association of 2 string lists in java

Tags: java

I am a relatively new programmer and am working on my first project to build a portfolio. In my project I have 2 rather large lists of strings (about 3.1 million) and I need to "associate" the elements in each one with a 1 to 1 relationship from predetermined values (elements are selected according to a set method) not just linearly (from top to bottom). For example:

```
lista(0) = list1(5);
listb(0) = list2(2);
lista(1) = list1(1);
listb(1) = list2(4);
lista(2) = list1(3);
listb(2) = list2(1);
```

The point of this is to reorder the lists in a manner that can be recreated at a later time or by a different program by "remembering" a set of values. I am using 2 lists because I need to be able to search one list for a String then pull the value from the corresponding element in the other list.

I have tried many different methods like storing each list in an arrayList then accessing the elements in the preset order and storing them in new arrayLists in the new order, then removing the elements from the old arrayLists. This would be ideal but didn't work because removing elements from a really large arrayList was very slow. I figured that removing an element from the lists will prevent it from being used again.

I tried storing them in String arrays, then accessing each element in the predefined method, storing them in another array then nulling out the elements so that they wont be used again, but creating null spaces made searching a nightmare, because if the program hit a null element during the predefined "move" value, I had to add in checks for nulls, then more movement which made things more complicated and harder to reproduce later.

I need an easy, and efficient way to create these associations between these 2 lists and ANY ideas are welcome. 
This is my first post to stackoverflow and I apologize if its formatted improperly or confusing, but please be gentle.

Comment: Using a database might be a step in the right direction if you want to store a bite more data.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to pull one value from a given string, why not using a map ? The key is the value of the first list and the value is the value of the second list

Answer (score 0):

use `Map<String,String>` which stores Key as a string and value as a string.And the best part is time complexity of removing an element would be O(1).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, Map is an option.More specifically [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), or another option could be [Hashtable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html). Make sure you look at what each has to offer. Some major differences are HashMap allows nulls but it is not synchronized. On the other hand Hashtable is synchronized and does not accept null as key.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! hashmap is a great idea for the final data structure, but my biggest trouble I'm running into is creating the "random" associations. If I start with both lists in a hashmap then I can't access it by index, which is what i need. The values are arbitrary until after the associations are made.

Comment: I don't think I'm getting what you trying to do

Comment: I am trying to develop a method that will allow me to select elements from each list in a specified order, almost randomly but needs to be able to be reproduced, not linearly, but never select the same elements twice, until each element in each list has a 1 to 1 relationship. Not sure if that makes any more sense. I've been working on it for a while, but I cannot think of a way to do it that is cheap and efficient.